# Clojure vs. Lisp: Why not concrete dotted pair in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, common-lisp

In [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153128/what-is-a-dotted-pairs-analogy-in-other-lisp-implementations) discussion, a poster (mikera) says

> There's no dotted pair in Clojure.
>
> A philosophical reason for this is that Clojure avoids the use of a
>   concrete "pair" data structure and instead emphasises abstract
>   "sequences" which can have may possible concrete implementations.

Can someone elaborate or point me to some literature on what this means? Is this a more elegant or mathematically pure approach?

Comment: It's just well.. more abstract approach (since clojure has it's roots in jvm, it is much like how collections framework and iterators function in java: abstractions over implementation, but brought a step further) this allows you to use the same set of functions on any data structure, be it lists, hash-maps, strings or queues for example.E.g it saves you from the `nth`, `gethash`, `elt` e.t.c set of functions from common lisp replacing it with simple `get`, And also lets you introduce new data structure (for example optimized) implementing needed protocols, that could be used idiomatically

Comment: Clojure is built on a data model where all the collections may be empty or may be extended with more items. One can add elements to a list/set/map/vector. One may not add an element to a pair. Clojure just doesn’t expose lists as cons cells.

Comment: I always hated the cons cell idea when I first saw Lisp in college (way back when...).  Having abstracted data types like Vector, HashMap, etc is way better so you can ignore details you don't care about (deliberately using Java-ey interface-like names here).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to a handy list of questions that Rich has answered about his design decisions https://gist.github.com/reborg/dc8b0c96c397a56668905e2767fd697f

While this list doesn't explicitly explain why there is no concrete "pair" data structure it might give you some insight into Rich's preference for practical, general design.

I remember there was a time when there was a discussion about introducing a "tuple" which would have been like a vector that only has two elements to avoid the needless memory allocation that occurs when using a two element vector.

Introducing these things has a complexity cost and so you can assume that the cost/benefit analysis did not warrant adding it to the code base.

Check out this discussion on Clojure's Jira project about adding tuples and you'll see how any idea gets put through its paces:

https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1517